# how to let the next bash loop wait until the program inside the loop is done?

Tags: bash

I realized that the following loop in a bash script will send `./a.out` to background, and the run will return to the system before even a single `./a.out` running is done.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1,2,3
do
    echo $i
    ./a.out 
done
```

The question is how to let the next bash loop wait until "./a.out" is done?

BTW, I thought this should be a common problem but didn't find similar questions, or I may need more searching skills...

Comment: Re: "the following loop in a bash script will send './a.out' to background": This is not true. What makes you think it is? (Also, you probably meant to write `for i in 1 2 3` rather than `for i in 1,2,3`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is the default behavior. You might be confused by the fact that your loop only runs once, with `i="1,2,3"`, and therefore appears to print all at once and then exit immediately.

Try `for i in 1 2 3` instead, and see if you get the output you expect.

Comment: It worked! Could you explain more about the difference between "for i in 1,2,3" and "for i in 1 2 3"?

Comment: The syntax is `for i in tokens...` Tokens are separated by whitespace, not commas or anything else.

Comment: I see, "1,2,3" is a single object in "for i in 1,2,3".

Comment: @HailiangZhang: If you're used to "normal" programming languages, one of the things that may throw you about shell scripting is that spaces aren't just something you put in to make the code easier to read; they're the primary delimiter in shell syntax. I see a lot of questions here that come from people getting scripts wrong, either because they left out required spaces, or added them someplace where they're forbidden. In the shell, spaces *matter*.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the "C style" for loop easier, ie:
    for ((i = 1 ; i < 4 ; i++))